# Beginner GPU passthrough Windows Host to Ubuntu Guest (Whats KVM? I use vBox)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I run win10 with 18.04LTS VM on virtual box.  I am not experienced in VM's but have a need for Linux (personal use) so I thought vBox was the only solution.

I have 2 discrete graphics cards so I want to passthrough one of these to the Ubuntu VM (also for my application to leverage this, and to explore/learn from using the GPU HW).

I believe my hardware is all supported (CPU / 2xGPU's discrete / Motherboard w/VT-D) but I cannot find a clear guide for my goal:  GPU passthrough to Ubuntu VM.

My questions:

1. Does this work?  (GPU passthrough win10 host --> ubuntu 18.04LTS guest)
2. Is there a clear tutorial/guide on this?
3. KVM or vBOX? (I have a vague impression KVM, which I have no experience with, is the better solution)

Any other help or feedback would be greatly appreciated

---

Update: 5/31/2020

I just wanted to make clear that I am not using this environment for gaming.  I work mostly from win10, but want to accelerate Matlab and Python inside my Linux guest w/GPU pass-through.

After some further reading, I'm unable to determine if virtualbox has any solution for my guest/host.  Instead, it might seem VMware vSphere or Workstation-Player might support pass-through.

Comment: You're abt 2 wks ahead of me (similar project). While collecting VT-D https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-virtualization-technology-for-directed-io-vt-d-enhancing-intel-platforms-for-efficient-virtualization-of-io-devices.html  info I know I will need I found https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/bios/enable-iommu-or-vt-d-in-your-bios.html  https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vt-x & https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vt-d Make sure Hyper-V is not enabled in Windows.

Comment: Check out these links and see if they help you:https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d & https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display

Comment: No mentions of GPU

Comment: Use a minimal Linux as hypervisor (host system) and use Windows as a guest system.

Comment: PS you might give **Windows Subsystem for Linux** a try to go -> there is also a very good X server for Windows 10 -> https://x410.dev/

Comment: if you're on windows, and passing thru to linux vm, use hyperv

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, GPU passthrough can't be done on virtualbox, and I am not sure you can even do it on windows.

There are different solutions to your specific need (run concurently windows and ubuntu with each having access to a gpu) :
Virtualization but not from windows. It is easier to setup two parallel system, one windows and one linux, from within an os dedicated to virtualization like unraid or proxmox. Both of them use kvm to do so. You can also have a not virtualised linux and windows in a vm, but this requires more setup steps. This is not what i would recommand for you as your usage of linux is light.

Much more in line with your initial need, wsl2. Windows subsystem for linux is nowaday a better experience for using linux inside of windows, and is now capable of using the GPUs.